# Every time I try to run adb my system becomes frozen

Tags: android-studio, adb

I'm working on Android Studio (3.3.2) under Ubuntu (18.04), and each time i try to run my app system becomes frozen and i have to force the restart. I have tried to downgrade the platform-tools (from 28.02 to 28 and even 27) but the fail persists.

Executing adb from command line produces the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running the app on the emulator or phone? Does it happen with every app?

Comment: @levdev Yeah. It happens even with new apps (simple MainActivity) and in both cases: emulator and phone

Comment: I found this, rather funnt actually https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2313496   BTW try to limit the problem, by example try with adb devices or with adb -h so you can see if is ADB itself or some action executed on adb

Comment: hi @cutiko adb devices produces the same situation. Also tried the solution described in the link and System even does not boot. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the boot mode of my BIOS from Legacy to UEFI and reinstalling Debian 9 afterwards solved the problem.